# SSRS Report Page Break for different number of rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a `SSRS` report where I want to display 15 rows on the first page and 25 rows on the following pages. I have `googled` and did not find any anything related to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

Handle it in SSRS

1. Create a new parent group
2. Make a custom group expression

   `=Floor((RowNumber(Nothing)+9)/25)`
3. Under Group properties go to page break option and select the option for page break between each group.

**Method 2**

Handle it in Sql.

1. Create a custom row number using partition function and using similar logic as group expression.
2. Group By new row Number
3. Do the page break between the groups.